# Member function not declared when using templates in classes (C++)

Tags: c++

I am using the following classes in my code

```
class pos2d
{
    float x, y;
public:
    float getx() const;
    float gety() const;
    //int getz() const;                    //How to avoid??
};

class pos3d
{
    float x, y, z;
public:
    float getx() const;
    float gety() const;
    float getz() const;
};

template<class T, class P>
class entity
{
    T type;
    P position;
public:
    void print() const;
};
```

My print function in class entity is as follows

```
template<class T, class P>
void entity<T, P>::print() const
{
    if (type == 1 || type == 'A')
        cout << "Object is of type " << type << " and has coordinates as (" << position.getx() << ", " << position.gety() << ", " << position.getz() << ")\n\n"; //Avoid getz in pos2d
    else if (type == 2 || type == 'B')
        cout << "Object is of type " << type << " and has coordinates as (" << position.getx() << ", " << position.gety() << ")\n\n";
}
```

> Note, Type value changes depending of whether class is pos2d or pos2d.

During compilation I get the following error:

> Error C2039   'getz': is not a member of 'pos2d'  Project1

I am aware that using a common get() function would solve this but i wish to be able to use getz() in my code without having it as part of another common function.

Comment: Retrieving the `z` coordinate of a 2D vector (or point) doesn't make sense.

Comment: Consider using sfinae. Have a look on documentation about  `std::enable_if`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is if you pass `pos2d` as template parameter the line

```
cout << "Object is of type " << type << " and has coordinates as (" << position.getx() << ", " << position.gety() << ", " << position.getz() << ")\n\n";
```

is still instantiated (`if` is done at runtime), the function cannot be resolved.

The usual way is to use specializations (`Type` parameter can be omitted):

```
template<class P>
class entity
{
    P position;
public:
    void print() const;
};

template<>
void entity<pos3d>::print() const
{
    cout << "Object is of type pos3d and has coordinates as (" 
         << position.getx() << ", " << position.gety() << ", " << position.getz() << ")\n\n";
}        

template<>
void entity<pos2d>::print() const
{
        cout << "Object is of type pos2d and has coordinates as (" 
             << position.getx() << ", " << position.gety() << ")\n\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 simple ways to implement this:

  - Make print() a member function of posX class.

  - Specialize print() function in entity class.

```
    #include <iostream>

    class pos2d
    {
        float x, y;
    public:
        float getx() const { return x; }
        float gety() const { return y; }
        void print() const
        {
            std::cout << "Object is of type and has coordinates as (" << getx() << ", " << gety() << ")\n\n";
        }
    };

    class pos3d
    {
        float x, y, z;
    public:
        float getx() const { return x; }
        float gety() const { return y; }
        float getz() const { return z; }
        void print() const
        {
            std::cout << "Object is of type  and has coordinates as (" << getx() << ", " << gety() << ", " << getz() << ")\n\n";
        }
    };

    template <class P>
    class entity
    {
        P position;
    public:
        void print() const { position.print(); }
        void print_specialized() const;
    };

    template <>
    void entity<pos3d>::print_specialized() const {
        std::cout << "Object is of type  and has coordinates as (" << position.getx() << ", " << position.gety() << ", " << position.getz() << ")\n\n";
    }

    template <>
    void entity<pos2d>::print_specialized() const  {
        std::cout << "Object is of type and has coordinates as (" << position.getx() << ", " << position.gety() << ")\n\n";
    }


    int main() {
        entity<pos2d> e;
        e.print();
        e.print_specialized();
        entity<pos3d> e2;
        e2.print();
        e2.print_specialized();
        return 0;
    }
```